# Global routing prefix in Core 3.1 API

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I have attribute `[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]` on every controller and this is redundant.

Is there a way to set the `api/v{version:apiVersion}/` part globally somewhere so I can just specify what the controller should be?

I've tried using a base controller, MapControllerRoute, and UsePathBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create an attribute that implements IRouteTemplateProvider

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to ensure that we use our default naming convension for controller routes
/// </summary>
public class DefaultRoutingAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider {
    public string Template => "api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]";
    /// <summary>
    /// Order is 2 to allow explicitly overriding the default route
    /// </summary>
    public int? Order => 2;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it like

```
[ApiController]
[DefaultRouting]
public class YourController : ControllerBase {}
```

I have not tested exactly your route with the apiversion but it works well with a simpler route in my application.